# Little "o" Notation

Tags: calculus, limits

As h approaches $0$, show $\sin(x+h)=\sin(x)+h\cos(x)+o(h)$. What I've done is basically substituted $h=0$ and therefore $LHS=RHS$, but I realise I'm supposed to use limits and I somehow can't get rid of the denominator $h$ everywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HINT**:

Use your knowledge of trigonometry to write $\sin(a+b)$ as some product/sum of $\cos(a), \cos(b), \sin(a),$ and $\sin(b)$.